# Problem in solving system of equations using "Solve"

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, wolfram-cloud

I have an equation in its normalized form as:
    $\frac{v(x)}{V_{cc}}=C_1\cos qx+C_2\sin qx+1+ \frac{q^2}{1-q^2}.\frac{V_R} 
{V_{cc}}\sin (x+\phi)$

Where
   $$q=\frac{1}{\omega\sqrt{LC}}$$
With the constants C1 and C2 equal to
 $C_1= -\cos(q\pi)-q \pi \sin(q\pi)+(\frac{q}{1-q^2})\frac{V_R}{V_{cc}} \times\begin{bmatrix} q \cos(q\pi) \sin \phi +(1-2q^2) \sin(q\pi) \cos \phi \end{bmatrix}$

$C_2= -\sin(q\pi)+q \pi \cos(q\pi)+(\frac{q}{1-q^2})\frac{V_R}{V_{cc}} \times   \begin{bmatrix} q \sin(q\pi) \sin \phi -(1-2q^2) \cos(q\pi) \cos \phi \end{bmatrix}$

**So I have set of three equations  as follows**

$V_R= -\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} v(x)\sin(x+\phi)dx$

$\begin{bmatrix}v(x)\end{bmatrix}_{x=2\pi}=0$
and
   $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{d v(x)}{d x}\end{bmatrix}_{x=2\pi}=0$$

I am trying to solve the above three equations for three unknown parameters  $$\phi,q, V_R$$ whereas  **Vcc** is a constant in my equations. The  three unknown parameters are reported  by the authors of the research article as

$\phi = -41.614$,$q=1.607$,$ V_R= 0.9253 \times V_{cc}$

I am solving the above set of three equations using **Solve** in Wolfram Mathematica but I get the error message as **Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>**. 
The complete notebook code that I use in Mathematica to solve it is given below

```
Clear[x, y, A, q, b, c, ysol, ysolsimp, c1, c2]
A = \[Omega]^2*L*C
b = Vcc
c = VR
d = q^2/(1 - q^2)
phi = \[Minus]41.614
q = 1.607
Vcc = 1
VR = 0.9253*Vcc 
eqn = Vcc + Vcc*c1*Cos[q*x] + Vcc*c2*Sin[q*x] + d*c*Sin[x + phi]
temp1 = D[eqn, x]
c1 = -Cos[q*Pi] - 
  q*Pi*Sin[q*Pi] + (d/q)*(VR/
     Vcc)*(q*Cos[q*Pi]* Sin[phi] + (1 - 2 q^2)*Sin[q*Pi]*Cos[phi])
c2 = -Sin[q*Pi] - 
  q*Pi*Cos[q*Pi] + (d/q)*(VR/
     Vcc)*(q*Sin[q*Pi]* Sin[phi] - (1 - 2 q^2)*Cos[q*Pi]*Cos[phi])
temp2 = -(1/\[Pi])*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(2  \[Pi]\)]\(eqn*
    Sin[x + phi] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
eqn1 = temp1 == c
eqn2 = eqn *b == 0 /. x -> 2*\[Pi]
eqn3 = temp1 == 0 /. x -> 2*\[Pi]
Solve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, {phi, VR, q}]

Solve::nsmet:This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>
```

The complete Wolfram Mathematica Notebook is also attached to this post. Kindly help me to debug the error. How can I get the same answer as that of the research article?  Thanking you.

Comment: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ebad13d0-9543-48da-9477-1140be4a482d

Comment: I think you can make the question simpler by just listings the equations and indicating which variables you are trying to solve for. It is hard to read of all this just to find this information out.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your valuable reply. I have edited the post and tried to make it simpler for a better understanding.  Looking forward for your valuable suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your code by converting to `Raw InputForm` (menu: `Cell | Convert To | Raw InputForm`) prior to copy and paste here.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thank you for your comment. I edited the code after following the steps mentioned in your comment. Looking forward to your valuable feedback. Thank you

Comment: Please add cross-post links to/from Wolfram Community post on same topic.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau   Thank you for your comment. I would like to add that I have posted a detailed post of the same question in the wolfram community. The link for the same is given below. [link](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1915576) .  Thank you all for your time to read my post giving valuable suggestions

Comment: Any Suggestions ?